# Create Primary Key other than Id in Jhipster Entity

Tags: jhipster

I want to create two entities.

Departments(Department Id,Department Name) and 
Employees(Employee Id, Employee Name, Address).

I want these primary keys for the tables:

Department Id for Departments,
Employee Id for Employees.

And Jhipster creates two tables as:
Departments(Id, Department Id, Department Name) and 
Empployee(Id, Employee Id, Employee Name, Address)

and it takes Id as a primary key in both of these tables.

In my Database Design I want Department Id and Employee Id as a primary key. So what to do next?

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: Ok, I will upload my jhipster-jdl.jh file here.

Comment: Then i run the command jhipster import-jdl jhipster-jdl.jh and then i run ./mvnw in my command line in root directory of my jhipster application. So, my application is started without any error and all the database tables are correctly created in mysql.

Comment: entity Department {
 departmentId Integer,
 departmentName String
}

entity Employee {
 employeeId Integer,
 employeeName String,
 address String
}

Comment: you'll be more likely of getting an answer if you edit your question with these informations. A well written question gets more views and answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**deperecated**]

You can't do it automatically in JHipster, you must edit generated code manually. A module could help at least for column names: https://github.com/bastienmichaux/generator-jhipster-db-helper

Comment: Can we generate entity in Jhipster other than command line 'jhipster entity employee' and jhipster-jdl.jh file?? as i don't find another way and my changelog.xml shows that id is a primary key and if i modify that file, the checksum does not match so in that case my jhipster project will not compile.

Comment: This is the only way, you got to reset checksums for liquibase (see liquibase doc) or drop your database. Otherwise you could create manually an additional  liquibase migration to later your columns. As soon as you work against Jhipster conventions, you have to do some manual work, no magic.

Comment: I meant "alter your columns".

Answer (score 9):

Support for custom ids was added in the new JHipster Release [v7.0.0](https://www.jhipster.tech/2021/03/21/jhipster-release-7.0.0.html).

In JDL you can write:

```
entity Foo {
  @Id customId Long
}
```

or

```
entity Foo {
  id UUID
}
```

see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/13258